# when i checked check box,How to get related row data in android?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a `ListView`with custom row. In custom row i have one checkBox and two textviews. Like that i have 5 custom rows in `Listview`. Now i checked first row check box and second row check box.Now i need to display those checked row's data in another screen.
snippet here

```
public class ProcessPurchaseOrder extends Activity{
HashMap<String, String> ProcessPOHashMap;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arListHashMap;
ListView processPOListView;
ProcessPOAdapter processPOAdapter;

@InjectView(R.id.processPONextBtn) protected Button procesPONxtBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.process_po);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    procesPONxtBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent drugSupplier = new Intent(ProcessPurchaseOrder.this, DrugSupplierActivity.class);
            startActivity(drugSupplier);

        }
    });

    arListHashMap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "crocin");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "300");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "500");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "zintac");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "200");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "anacin");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "tapic-EM");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "omnacartil 5mg");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "maxiguard 250mg");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "c-led");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "1000 mcg");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "omikind");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "nice");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "900");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "100");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "omez");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "tellmekind 40mg");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "Amlokind-at");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "gatimac 400mg");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);

    ProcessPOHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("DrugName", "nupenta-DSR");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyAvail", "400");
    ProcessPOHashMap.put("QtyOrderd", "400");
    arListHashMap.add(ProcessPOHashMap);
    processPOListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.processPOListView);
    processPOAdapter= new ProcessPOAdapter(ProcessPurchaseOrder.this, arListHashMap);
    processPOListView.setAdapter(processPOAdapter);

}}`
```

`AdapterClass` is here

```
public class ProcessPOAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
Activity context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
HashMap<String, String> mapdata;

public ProcessPOAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox drugCheck;
    TextView drugName;
    TextView qtyAvail;
    TextView qtyOrderd;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    mapdata = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapdata = data.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.process_po_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.drugCheck = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBoxDrugs);
        holder.drugName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDrugValue);
        holder.qtyAvail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQtyAvailValue);
        holder.qtyOrderd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQtyOrderdValue);
        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.drugName.setText(mapdata.get("DrugName"));
    holder.qtyAvail.setText(mapdata.get("QtyAvail"));
    holder.qtyOrderd.setText(mapdata.get("QtyOrderd"));
    return convertView;
}

}
```

Comment: you have all static data..???

Comment: yes, right now it is a static data... once functionality is ready then will integrate api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should use an object instead of a map but thats not the issue here.

You need to have a create a HashSet of your object or map to store checked items in your adapter otherwise since views are reauses in list, you check items will change while scrolling.

Here is you code updated with those changes

```
public class ProcessPOAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
Activity context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
HashMap<String, String> mapdata;
private HashSet<HashMap<String, String>> selectedItems = new HashSet<HashMap<String, String>>();

public ProcessPOAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox drugCheck;
    TextView drugName;
    TextView qtyAvail;
    TextView qtyOrderd;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    mapdata = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapdata = data.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.process_po_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.drugCheck = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBoxDrugs);
        holder.drugCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
        holder.drugName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDrugValue);
        holder.qtyAvail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQtyAvailValue);
        holder.qtyOrderd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQtyOrderdValue);
        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.drugCheck.setTag(mapdata);//link object to retrieve it later in onCheckedChanged
    holder.drugCheck.setChecked(selectedItems.contains(mapdata));
    holder.drugName.setText(mapdata.get("DrugName"));
    holder.qtyAvail.setText(mapdata.get("QtyAvail"));
    holder.qtyOrderd.setText(mapdata.get("QtyOrderd"));
    return convertView;
}

private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mapdata = (HashMap<String, String>) buttonView.getTag();
        boolean isSelected = selectedItems.contains(mapdata);
        if(isSelected!=isChecked){ // protection to avoid updating selection when calling setChecked() from getView()
            if(isChecked){
                selectedItems.add(mapdata);
            }else{
                selectedItems.remove(mapdata);
            }
        }
    }
};

public List<HashMap<String, String>> getSelectedItems(){
    List<HashMap<String, String>> ret = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for(HashMap<String, String> item : selectedItems){
        ret.add(item);
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```

If it doesn't work using HashMap (i don't know the hashMap.equals/.hashCode implementation) try using custom objetcs.

You can select/deselect all by adding all your items to selectItems/clearing it. you might need to call notifyDataSetChanged(); for your list to actualy update it's views.

EDIT:

To send it to your other activity

```
 yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putSerializable("key", yourAddapter.getSelectedItems()); //Your data
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And to retrieve it in your second activity

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
list<HashMap<String, String>> list = b.getSerializable("key");
```

Comment: very happy,thank you,this is working for me... how to send this list to another class?

Comment: Just call the getSelectedItems(); method i added in your addapter to retrieve your items. How you pass it depend on what exactly is your other class (activity? fragment?).

Comment: when i click next button then this arraylist pass to another activity

Comment: hi,,, thank you for your valuable suggestions... every thing is fine... last one day i am searching for how to get arraylist from adapter class and send to another activity... when i click next button... now i got good clarity with ur code... getSelectdItem() method giving error... can u explain me why it is showing error

Comment: that array list is in adapter class...i need to send this list to another activity from this activity. How to get array list from adapter class to associated class.

Comment: Well i added getSelectedItems() method to our custom adapter. so just call yourAdapter.getSelectedItems() from your activity. Il will give you a copy of this list.

Comment: thank u so much for sending your valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

public class ProcessPOAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
Activity context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
HashMap<String, String> mapdata;
private HashSet<HashMap<String, String>> selectedItems = new HashSet<HashMap<String, String>>();

public ProcessPOAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox drugCheck;
    TextView drugName;
    TextView qtyAvail;
    TextView qtyOrderd;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    mapdata = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapdata = data.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.process_po_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.drugCheck = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBoxDrugs);
        holder.drugCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
        holder.drugName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDrugValue);
        holder.qtyAvail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQtyAvailValue);
        holder.qtyOrderd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQtyOrderdValue);
        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.drugCheck.setTag(mapdata);//link object to retrieve it later in onCheckedChanged
     holder.drugCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckchangeListener(position));
    holder.drugCheck.setChecked(selectedItems.contains(mapdata));

    holder.drugName.setText(mapdata.get("DrugName"));
    holder.qtyAvail.setText(mapdata.get("QtyAvail"));
    holder.qtyOrderd.setText(mapdata.get("QtyOrderd"));
    return convertView;
}

class CheckchangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

        int position;

        public CheckchangeListener(int position) {

            this.position = position;


        }

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mapdata = data.get(position);
        boolean isSelected = selectedItems.contains(mapdata);
        if(isSelected!=isChecked){ // protection to avoid updating selection when calling setChecked() from getView()
            if(isChecked){
                selectedItems.add(mapdata);
            }else{
                selectedItems.remove(mapdata);
            }
        }
    }
}
}

public List<HashMap<String, String>> getSelectedItems(){
    List<HashMap<String, String>> ret = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for(HashMap<String, String> item : selectedItems){
        ret.add(item);
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```